# Merge overlapping CGRects

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, cgrect

If I have a class `Button`:

```
class Button: Hashable {
    private let id: String
    var name: String
    var rect: CGRect    
}
```

I also have an array of `Button`: `var buttons: [Button]`, how would I merge every overlapping button in the `buttons` array? `CGRect` has an `intersects() -> Bool` and `union() -> CGRect` functions.

I tried this and was getting index out of range errors:

```
for i in 0..<buttons.count {
        for j in (i+1)..<buttons.count {
            if buttons[i].rect.intersects(buttons[j].rect) {
                let secondRect = buttons[j].rect
                let union = buttons[i].rect.union(secondRect)
                buttons[i].rect = union
                buttons.remove(at: j)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift `for` loop is static, which means that range of the index determined at the start. While `buttons.count` keeps decreasing when you remove a next item, both `i` and `j` are counting til the start `buttons.count`, that's why you get a crash.

There's no dynamic `for` in swift (c-like), that's why you have to use while instead:

```
var i = 0
while i < buttons.count {
    var j = i + 1
    while j < buttons.count {
        if buttons[i].rect.intersects(buttons[j].rect) {
            let secondRect = buttons[j].rect
            let union = buttons[i].rect.union(secondRect)
            buttons[i].rect = union
            buttons.remove(at: j)
        } else {
            j += 1
        }
    }
    i += 1
}
```